# How do I access the value of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

How am I to retrieve the value of the specific symbol I am looking at?

If I defined a symbol in a hash earlier as such

```
:red => "blue"
```

What method can I invoke on :red to get "blue"? .to_s and .id2name give me "red"

Comment: Ruby's documentation is quite good, accessing keys and values is covered in the introduction for [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html).

Comment: thanks, because I was trying to access it in an array that was defined outside of the hash I overlooked the simple answer as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
>> h = {:red => "blue"}
=> {:red=>"blue"}
>> h[:red]
=> "blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`Hash#fetch`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

```
h = {:red => "blue"}
h.fetch(:red) # => "blue"
```